# Symfony 2: Resource not found error while loading URI - 404 error

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Below are details:

**File Structure**
[image]

**routing.yml**

```
app_api:
#     resource: "@TemplateManager/Bundle/DocumentGeneratorBundle/Controller/API"
     resource: "@TemplateManagerDocumentGeneratorBundle/Controller/API"
     type:     annotation
```

**routing_dev.yml**

```
app_api:
     resource: "@TemplateManager/Bundle/DocumentGeneratorBundle/Controller/API"
#     resource: "@TemplateManagerDocumentGeneratorBundle/Controller/API"
     type:     annotation
```

**App Kernel**

```
$bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle\TemplateManagerDocumentGeneratorBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        );
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle\Controller\API;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;



class ClientController
{
    /**
     * @Route("api/clients")
     * @Method("GET")
     */

    public function allAction()
    {
        return new Response("Lets Do this");
    }
}
```

**DocumentGeneratorBundle**

```
namespace TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;

class TemplateManagerDocumentGeneratorBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

**App Console Error for Routing**

```
 php app/console router:debug
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                                                      
  Cannot load resource "@TemplateManager/Bundle/DocumentGeneratorBundle/Controller/API". Make sure the "TemplateManager" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the applicat  
  ion kernel class.
```

**Error while accessing URI**

> TwigBundle:Exception:error404.html.twig

Comment: Your controller class needs `extends Controller` in its signature.

Comment: @HaydenSchiff Done but error remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to duplicate this config into routing.yml and routing_dev.yml

This line: `resource: "@TemplateManagerDocumentGeneratorBundle/Controller/API"` should be correct. Delete commented line from `routing.yml`, and delete `app_api` entry from `routing_dev.yml`.

If it  isn't still correct, please post content of `...Bundle.php` file inside `src/TemplateManager/Bundle/DocumentGeneratorBundle/` dir.

Comment: The content pasted on original question what you said, it does not give route debug error anymore but still I am not able to access URI, same 404

Comment: Please post result of `app/console debug:router` command (or `router:debug` if it's old Symfony).

Comment: php app/console router:debug
[router] Current routes
 Name Method Scheme Host Path

Comment: Please add `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;` to your `ClientController`, and try again. Also please update your code examples - it misses extending base Controller class.